HTML5 Simple Video Player with Javascript Play Button Doesn't Provide a Thumbnail Preview on Mobile
I have this relatively simple code but it doesn't give a thumbnail preview on mobile, only on web does it provide a blackbox background. What causes this behaviour and how do I fix it please?


    var video = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");
    var playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");

    // Hide other controls
    video.controls = false;

    // Play the video when play button is clicked
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        video.play();
        playButton.style.display = "none";
    });

    // Pause the video and show play button when anywhere on video is clicked
    video.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (video.paused) {
            video.play();
            playButton.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            video.pause();
            playButton.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
    #videoContainer {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
    }

    #playButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
    }
<div id="videoContainer">
    <video id="videoPlayer" loop playsinline width="300">
        <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
                type="video/mp4">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
    </video>

    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
</div>




Since you did not specify any value for the preload attribute, the mobile browsers are probably using none as default. But rather than switching that to auto, you should probably specify a poster image.

@Jimmy I assume "A blackbox background" here means "The first frame"? Try adding muted to your video tag setup. If that still fails, keep the muted in HTML but also now add into the JS, a video.currentTime = 0; video.pause(); (maybe after the video.controls = false;). The idea is to trick the player into showing a first frame (there is no autoplay in mobile if the video is not in a muted mode. Showing the first frame could be considered as a form of auto-playing).
